# Google Sheets App Script-Macro: How do I copy an image from one cell and paste it into another

Tags: javascript, image, google-sheets, copy-paste

I am trying to store the value of any current cell (image in G1 for this example) and paste it into a range of merged cells (A1:C1).  This will essentially enlarge the picture for better viewing.  It would be used by selecting a cell and executing a macro.

If I use **.setvalue** it will not work with an image.  It only works with text, intergers, etc.
If I use **.copyTo** I get an error when debugging.  Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' line: 21 file: macros.gs

You can copy and paste an image outside of an app script by simply using Copy/Paste, so there must be a way to do it using a script.

Beyond these failed solutions, is there any other way to enlarge an image temporarily?  I'm looking for any other creative suggestion.  It could open in a browser window or any pop-up.  It must use an image in a cell (not over a cell) and must be stored in the document (not a linked file).

Unfortunately, my security settings will not allow me to upload a picture of my actually sheet, so you'll have to use your imagination.

```html
function CopyPaste() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();   
  var activeCellValue = activeCell.getValue();        
  var target = activeSheet.getRange('A1:C1');

  // target.setValue(activeCellValue);  ---- Attempt 1) This doesn't work with an image
  
  // spreadsheet.getRange(activeCellValue).copyTo(target), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);  ---- Attempt 2) This returns an error when debugging
  
  // SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The active cell value is "+activeCellValue);  ---- I just used this to see what value is stored.  It is not necessary.

};
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About `Unfortunately, my security settings will not allow me to upload a picture of my actually sheet, so you'll have to use your imagination.`, I understand it. So, can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Please do ask about the detail of my question.  In it’s shortest form, I want to create a macro that allows me to copy a picture from the current cell and paste it into a given cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.